# How to set button tag and cell tag similar in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

I have a table containing labels and buttons.on that button i have generated drop down list . i want to set cell tag and button tag similar. b'cos according to that i have to maintain my function. for your reference following image ll give you idea

[image: As per image, Suppose consider i am having 4 records means the "indexpath.row" for cell is 0-11 now i want to set my button tag and cell tag according following series 0 1 2 3 3 4 5 5 6 7 7 8 9 9 10 11 11 and so on b'cos data records are dynamic.]

This is my code in CellForRowAtIndexPath :-NSString *s;
    Var=0;

```
if(indexPath.row<=2)
{
  btn_click.tag=indexPath.row;

    s =[dict valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]];
}
else
{
    if (indexPath.row%3==0)
    {
        Var=(NSInteger)(indexPath.row/3);

    }
    else
    {
        Var=Var+1;
    }

    if(indexPath.row%3==0 && Var==1)
    {       

        btn_click.tag=indexPath.row;
         s =[dict valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]];

    }

    else 
    {
        if (Var>1)
        {
            Var=1;
        }
        btn_click.tag=indexPath.row-Var;
        s =[dict valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row-Var]];
    }

}
NSLog(@"CELLTAGTag%d",btn_click.tag);
```

}

Thanks & Regards,
Priyanka.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the Button the tag as `indexPath.row`. Hence you can get the cell using the row value which is also the `tag` for the `UIButton`

```
yourButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to give the same tag number to both the cellView and buttonView depanding on the cell row number you can do the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomTableCell";
    static NSString *CellNib = @"UserCustomTableCell";

    UserCustomTableCell *cell = (UserCustomTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellNib owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (UserCustomTableCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.myButton.tag = [indexPath.row];
    cell.tag = [indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```